# How do I make an image move on its own in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uigesturerecognizer

This is my code regarding making my image move randomly upon being clicked (using gestures recognizer).

But I would like this to happen constantly and automatically, that it is moving around by itself non stop.

```
let x = Int.random(in: 0...275)
let y = Int.random(in: 210...565)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    self.randomView.center.y = CGFloat(y)
    self.randomView.center.x = CGFloat(x)
}, completion: nil)
```

If needed I can share the entire code from the ViewController file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Was not aware about that. And sorry I am new to swift, can you please further explain your first message? Thanks

Comment: Ah I see, and thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? Using animate was the only option I found to make to jump around, I was not aware of any other ways. If there is another better way, I would appreciate if you told me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your question, you can recursively call the method, with a delay.

That having been said, you do not appear to be animating at all. If you just want to move it to different location, you could do:

```swift
weak var timer: Timer?

func moveToRandomLocation() {
    let x = Int.random(in: 0...275)
    let y = Int.random(in: 210...565)
    
    randomView.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.moveToRandomLocation()
    }
}
```

That moves it, and a half of a second later, calls itself. And the `[weak self]` capture list avoids the strong reference cycle. And I use a `Timer` the timer `invalidate` that timer should you want to stop it.

---

Or, just use a repeating `Timer`:

```swift
weak var timer: Timer?

func startMovingToRandomLocations() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
        let x = Int.random(in: 0...275)
        let y = Int.random(in: 210...565)
        self?.randomView.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
```

Either way, when you want to stop it (including in `deinit` implementation), call:

```swift
timer?.invalidate()
```

---

Now, if you wanted to animate, you would use a non-zero duration.

```swift
func moveToRandomLocation() {
    let x = Int.random(in: 0...275)
    let y = Int.random(in: 210...565)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear) {
        self.randomView.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    } completion: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.moveToRandomLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave selected this as the correct answer for the better suggestion to use a timer, as so others would find some help if one is in the same situation as me. 

Though I would like to ask something irrelevent to this, about how to basically make it so when someone closes an alert by using the button displayed it would call a function.